# Что не так с путём?

Tags: python, django, логирование, path

Что ему надо то ?

файл создается в директории log/application.log

вот BASE_DIR:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

вот такой мой код в settings

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    }
},
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format':
        '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {message}',
        'style':
        '{',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'C://Users/Admin/Django_projects/django_TZ/src/log/application.log',
        'formatters': 'verbose',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'django.db.backends': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['file'],
    },
}
}
```

Вывод ошибки:

```
  Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\logging\config.py", line 564, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\logging\config.py", line 745, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'formatters'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Django_projects\django_TZ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Django_projects\django_TZ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Django_projects\django_TZ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Django_projects\django_TZ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Django_projects\django_TZ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Django_projects\django_TZ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Django_projects\django_TZ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\logging\config.py", line 809, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\logging\config.py", line 571, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'
```

Comment: я пробовал и так:   BASE_DIR.joinpath('log/application.log')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вижу смысла в принципе указывать полный путь здесь

```py
...
'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'C://Users/Admin/Django_projects/django_TZ/src/log/application.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    }
```

Поскольку проект может работать в различных ОС или на просто на другой машине.

Вариантом для решения может быть указание пути в таком формате (как пример, я не знаю структуры вашего проекта)

```py
'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': './src/log/application.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    }
```

Здесь `.` - это и есть ваша папка с проектом или `BASE_DIR`. Здесь путь указывается относительно директории с проектом, что дает возможность не писать лишние конфигурации и следить за этим отдельно.

**UPD** В вопросе так же ошибка с ключом. Необходимо использовать ключ `formatter` (в вопросе используется `formatters`) при указании какой формат сообщения будет использован

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но это мне не помогло

Comment: Да, там еще ошибка с ключом. Надо исправить с `'formatters':` на `'formatter':`

Comment: 'formatter': 'verbose',  ты был прав!! Спасибо

Comment: @Айдын если мой ответ оказался полезен отметьте его как принятый. Это поможет тем кто столкнеться с таким же вопросом